# Selecting several layers programmatically using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, layers, c++, select

In my plugin I want to select some layers programmatically. But with

`virtual QList<QgsMapLayer *> QgsLegendInterface::selectedLayers(bool inDrawOrder = false)`

I only receive the actually selected layers.

I've tried in `QgsLayerTreeView` the method `void QgsLayerTreeView::setCurrentLayer(QgsMapLayer * layer)` But I only can select one Layer, and I need to select more layers.

Any idea what could I try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find the way directly from the QGIS API. However, you can achieve it using Qt4.

You need to temporarily set the selection mode of the layer tree view to multi-selection, select all your layers, and then set the selection mode back.

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QAbstractItemView
iface.layerTreeView().setSelectionMode( QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection )

# Select your layers, this time they are not mutually exclusive
iface.layerTreeView().setCurrentLayer(layer1)
iface.layerTreeView().setCurrentLayer(layer2)
iface.layerTreeView().setCurrentLayer(layer3)

iface.layerTreeView().setSelectionMode( QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection )
```

For **QGIS 3**, replace `from PyQt4.QtGui import QAbstractItemView` with `from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QAbstractItemView` to use PyQt5